# Extending store class in Mobx Flutter

Tags: flutter

What is the correct way to extend a store class in Mobx in flutter? Wherever I try to put 'extends' i get a compilation error.

```dart
class Booking = _Booking with _$Booking;

abstract class _Booking with Store {}


class FlightBooking  = _FlightBooking with _$FlightBooking ;

abstract class _FlightBooking with Store {}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that by making `_FlightBooking` extend `Booking`:

```
class FlightBooking  = _FlightBooking with _$FlightBooking ;


abstract class _FlightBooking extends Booking with Store {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Store` of mobx is a mixin, not a class. Mixins cannot be used to extend. You might want to look more into the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins).